# How can I test that a callback *doesn't* get run?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I would like to **test that a particular function does not run a callback** during a test. Eg, in my simplified code below, checker.check() checks numbers, and the numbers given in this particular test **should not** run the callback.

```
test('Do not raise false alerts', function(done){
    var checker = setupChecker(function(){
        done('bad alert')
    })
    checker.check(60)
    checker.check(70)
    checker.check(80)
})
```

Essentially I would like the test to timeout if `done()` is never called.

I could of course use `setTimeout()` for this purpose, but I thought there might something built into Mocha for this purpose.

I could also add a second callback to checker() for when an alert shouldn't be raised, but that strikes me [test-induced design damage](http://david.heinemeierhansson.com/2014/test-induced-design-damage.html) and I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Can't you run the test with numbers that should run the callback, to confirm the test is working?

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, I already have a separate test for raising alerts. I consider raising alerts and not raising false alerts as separate functionality that needs to be tested. Eg, the code could alert all the time and still pass the raising alerts test.

Comment: @isi Sorry I don't understand what 'You can't you always need to workaround such issues in asynchronous communication.' means. Re: `setTimeout()` I have addressed that in my question.

Comment: @isi I understand what I think you're trying to say (although your English is hard to understand). See my point re: `setTimeout()` in the question you're responding to.

Comment: Sry for raising the confusion level. I was trying to say: I think you'll need to go the route using a timeout, as you already mentioned in your question. Or alternatively, use a polling mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

The best place for such kind of assertion is `exit` event of `process`, because nothing can happen after that (well, except other `exit` listeners, keep that in mind):

```
test('Do not raise false alerts', function(){
    var badAlert = false;
    var checker = setupChecker(function(){
        badAlert = true
    })

    process.on('exit', function () {
      assert.ok(!badAlert);
    });


    checker.check(60)
    checker.check(70)
    checker.check(80)
})
```

Unfortunately this pattern doesn't work really nice with mocha. It will show that a test passes and then a stack trace in case of failure.

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what I'm looking for. I wasn't sure for a moment if the process actually exits on each test but checking it, it seems like it does. Compared to `setTimeout()` using `process.on('exit')` means I have a single timeout rather than two.

Comment: the problem with `setTimeout` is that a callback still can be called later. Also timeout will hold process alive though it can be the only active thing and there is no chance that callback will called

Comment: Are you totally sure this works? Even a simple `process.on('exit', function(){ done() });` inside `test` seems to fail.

Comment: indeed, this pattern doesn't work nice with mocha. Two ideas: mocha uses timeouts for async tests, so the `exit` event fires only after timeout failure (timeout 0 forces process to stay alive, probably via `setInterval`). Also mocha probably uses `exit` event to count callbacks. I will add a workaround

Comment: Totally forgot: mocha runs async tests one by one, that's why putting `done` in `exit` listener makes no sense